# Where do I put image style definition in a module?

Tags: hooks, media

I'm writing a custom node formatter that needs to use a certain image style. Since I don't want to rely on that image style being defined by the admin, and I want to be sure the style is not deleted, I am going to provide the style definition in code.

Should MYMODULE_image_default_styles go into the .install or .module file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the hook implementations go in the module file, not the in the installation file.

Hooks that needs to be in the installation file are, for example, `hook_install()`, `hook_requirements()`, `hook_schema()`, and `hook_uninstall()`.
[hook_image_default_styles()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.api.php/function/hook_image_default_styles/7) needs to be in the module file, or the file that [hook_hook_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info/7) reports to contain that hook implementation.

[image_image_default_styles()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_image_default_styles/7), for example, is contained in the [image.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/7) file.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) and export it, then in your .info file add dependency to it.

other solution is what you say, put it inside MYMODULE_image_default_styles in your .module and re-install your module to make it locked in admin